# Set of all triples making a piecewise function differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $$f(x)=ax^2+b ,x\le1$$$$f(x)=cx^4-2x^2,x>1$$ is differentiable at 1.

I assumed that I was supposed to use the limit definition of the derivative somehow, but this is giving me trouble since the function is piecewise and there are so many different possibilities for $(a, b, c)$.  I'm honestly not really sure how to approach the problem; does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For a function to be differentiable it must be continuous.

$\implies a+b = c-2$

and

$f'(1^-) = f'(1^+) \implies 2a = 4c-4\implies a = 2c-2$

substituing $a=2c-2$ into $a+b = c-2$

$2c-2 + b = c-2 \implies b = -c$

$(2c-2,-c,c)$ is the required triple.